# A condition for a profunctor to be representable

Tags: category-theory, profunctors

I was wondering if there is an easy way to check whether a given profunctor
$$
p : {\cal C}^{op}\times{\cal D} \to \sf Set
$$ is "representable" in the sense that $p$ is the functor ${\cal D}(F,1)$ for some functor $F :{\cal C} \to {\cal D}$.

More precisely, I was wondering if it is possible to read representability in the "[collage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cograph+of+a+profunctor)" of $p$, i.e. its category of elements, meaning that I would like something that sounds as

> the following conditions are equivalent for $p : {\cal C}^{op}\times{\cal D} \to \sf Set$:
>
> 1. $p$ is representable;
> 2. $El(p)$ has property $\Gamma$.

for some property $\Gamma$ to be determined.

This condition can certainly not be that $El(p)$ has a terminal object, because even if $p$ can certainly be regarded as a presheaf on ${\cal C}\times {\cal D}^{op}$, that condition yields something different/stronger, i.e. the fact that
$$ p(X,Y) = {\cal C}(X,U) \times {\cal D}(V,Y)$$
for a unique object $(U,V)\in {\cal C}\times{\cal D}^{op}$ (and consequently $p$ acts on morphisms as pre/post composition). So, there's also a small clash of notation, because a profunctor $p$ is not representable in the sense above iff it is representable as a presheaf on ${\cal C}\times{\cal D}^{op}$... which is fine, but mixing the two terminologies doesn't allow me to exploit "representability" theorems for presheaves as black boxes.

Is there something obvious I fail to see?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose by $\mathcal D(F,1)$ you mean the functor $(c,d)\mapsto \mathcal D(Fc,d)$.

Then $\Gamma$ is simply:

> $\mathcal D$ is a *reflective* subcategory of the collage category.

We obtain $F$ (up to natural isomorphism) as the reflection functor (restricted to $\mathcal C$).

Note that the category of elements is a bit different than the collage category: it has the heteromorphisms (elements of $p(c,d)$) *as objects*.
Actually it's the full subcategory of a 'flipped' arrow category of the collage, restricted to heteromorphisms.